# Raspberry Pi Compute Module 3+ yocto usb ethernet found but not working

Tags: usb, ethernet, driver, yocto

I've created my own very basic console distro with yocto and uploaded it to a compute module 3+. Everything works so far, but I am unable to access internet via the connected AXIS AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet (USB to ethernet adapter).

It is found by using the command

```
lsusb
```

And running

```
dmesg | grep ASIX
```

Returns

*ax88179_178a 1-1.3:1.0 eth0: register 'ax88179_178a' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.3 ...*

But it's not working. Are there something I need to include in the conf files before creating the image or is there something I can do without re-making the image?

Comment: From similar work in initramfs: did you build the supporting driver into the kernel? (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/185739/5477 )

Comment: @Piskvor I see. Do I need to put these into the raspberrypi kernel recipe before building?- or do they need to go somewhere else?- and how would I include them?

Comment: I'm not familiar with yocto recipes, but from a few casual searches, I suspect this needs to be in the kernel recipe.